# How to schedule multiple local notifications without freezing UI?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, uilocalnotification, phonegap-plugins

In my PhoneGap 1.3 offline app I'm using modified iOS local notification plugin found in official plugin GitHub page.

I need to schedule a repeating notification (weekly/monthly), or multiple single notifications fired on every 2 weeks, based on user defined setting.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to schedule those 26 notifications to be fired on every 2 weeks.

Currently I'm using this to achieve that:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (localNotif == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: i * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2];

    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i: %@", i, msg];

    localNotif.hasAction = NO;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];        

    [localNotif release];

}
```

When running this on iPhone 3G or iPod Touch 2 the UI freezes for about 3 - 5 seconds which is a big no no. Is there a way to optimize scheduling notifications?

I know that using only weekly and monthly repeating notifications would solve the problem but the client wants `every 2 weeks`, `every 2 months`, and `every 3 months` notifications, so I need to schedule multiple notifications.

I have tried to run the loop in new thread using `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:...]` which raises new problems (crashes every now and then).

Are iPhones released after 3G that much faster that delay/froze won't exist? I only have those 2 ancient devices to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either performing the creation in a background thread using this: `(void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg`

Or I would try to rethink the process. Perhaps instead of creating a years worth of 2 week reminders at once just create a couple and set something else up to create the rest. Or maybe even just create one and store a repeating bool with it so when it fires it also creates the next one.

Comment: I already have tried to create only one and then reschedule another when it's fired. But the problem was it only worked when app was running or in background. Im my appDelegate's didReceiveLocalNotification I created a new notification and scheduled it. What do you mean by "store a repeating bool with it so when it fires it also creates the next one". An example much appreciated. :)

Comment: Im just speaking purely thearetically if you've tried it and it didn't work I believe you.